# loop through ranges and custom outputs

Tags: ruby, for-loop, range

```
puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
num = gets.to_i

if (0..100).step(0) do |n|
#     n = 10
#     n = 20
#     n = 30
#     ...
    puts 'Thanks. You inserted ' + num.to_s + '!'

#    # using case 
#    case num2
#    when 60
#      puts "Student gets F grade"
#    when 60..70
#      puts "Student gets D grade"    
#    when 70..80
#      puts "Student gets C grade"    
#    when 80..90
#      puts "Student gets B grade"    
#    when 90..100
#      puts "Student gets A grade"    
#    else
#      puts "Grade not available for that value."
#    end    

else n => (100)

    puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
    num = gets.to_i
    puts 'Thanks. You inserted ' + num.to_s + '!'

end
```

- the commented out code above is what I'm trying to eliminate and
  accomplish with a `for else` *loop* in ruby.
- Essentially I want to check if user enters a number within the
  *valid* range `(0 - 100)` and then execute code associated with it, if user enters number outside of range to try again using `else`.
- I want to spit out a letter grade correlating to the value entered.
  **So if** valid value is entered -> get grade associated with -> else '*Please try again*'. Any thoughts how to achieve this with a more
  optimal loop, rather then my annoying multiple cases previous code?

***update:***

```
puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
num = gets.to_i

while !num.between?(1, 100)
#num = gets.chomp.to_i

grade = loop do
  puts 'Check your score!'
  input = gets.to_i  
  case input
  when 1..60
    break 'F'
  when 60..70
    break 'D'
  when 70..80
    break 'C'      
  when 80..90
    break 'B'
  when 90..100
    break 'A'              
  else
    puts 'Please insert a VALID number between 1 and 100.'
    num = gets.to_i
  end      
end    

puts "Your grade is #{grade}"

end
```

Comment: It looks to me like you combined two separate answers from below and ended up with a mess. You have two loops with one inside the other, and you have three separate calls to `gets`.  You might want to take a step back and understand what you're really doing.

Comment: You'll rarely see `for..else..end`. The Ruby-way is to instead use blocks with enumerators, such as `obj.each { ... }`, `obj.map { ... }` and so on. That is in part because blocks create a new scope which hides information from other parts of the code. If `for..else..end` were dropped from the language it would cause havoc with some existing apps, but it wouldn't be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many ways to obtain your desired result in a Ruby-like fashion.

```
NumberToLetter = [['F', 59], ['D', 69], ['C', 79], ['B', 89], ['A', 100]]

def letter_grade
  num = number_grade
  letter, _ = NumberToLetter.find { |_, n| num <= n }
  [num, letter]
end

def number_grade
  loop do
    puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
    num = gets.to_i
    break(num) if (1..100).cover?(num)
  end
end

10.times { print letter_grade; puts }
# [43, "F"]
# [59, "F"]
# [60, "D"]
# [69, "D"]
# [70, "C"]
# [79, "C"]
# [80, "B"]
# [89, "B"]
# [90, "A"]
# [100, "A"]
```

The first element of each two-element array returned is the number entered by the user. The second is the associated grade.

I adopted the Ruby convention of representing a local variable that is not used in calculations with an underscore (`'_'`), which is in fact a valid variable name.

Comment: I like how you separated the collection of a valid input from the actual conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right idea with the case-expression. Just put it all into a `loop` and assign its return value to a variable. In the case-branches use `break('grade')`

```
grade = loop do
  puts 'What\'s your score'
  input = gets.to_i  
  case input
  when 1..10
    break 'F'
  when 11..20
    break 'E'
  else
    puts 'invalid score try again'
  end
end

puts "Your grade is #{grade}"
```

Comment: Thanks using this I've gotten close, I've updated the Q.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler as you think, if now I understand, you just need to ask while the input of the user is in the range you want, if it is you skip the while and do what you want:

The full code would be:

```
puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
num = gets.to_i

while not num.between?(0,100) do

    puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
    num = gets.to_i

end

puts 'Thanks. You inserted ' + num.to_s + '!'
case num
  when 60
    puts "Student gets F grade"
  when 60..70
    puts "Student gets D grade"    
  when 70..80
    puts "Student gets C grade"    
  when 80..90
    puts "Student gets B grade"    
  when 90..100
    puts "Student gets A grade"    
  else
    puts "Grade not available for that value."
end
```

Comment: How does this associate the letter grade with the value?

Comment: @Dr.KennethNoisewater sorry I don't fully understand the question, what do you mean with letter grade with what value?

Comment: @JoshBrody haha thanks but I made a huge mistake before so now I'm a little confused

Comment: @Dr.KennethNoisewater now I understood, I modified the answer now it does what you wanted in the first place

Comment: You should be able to refactor this to avoid two different `gets` calls.

Comment: A tiny point: to avoid the negative, consider `until num.between?(0,100)` instead of `while not num.between?(0,100)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-engineering this.

```
num = 0 

while !num.between?(1, 100)
  puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
  num = gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts "Thanks, #{num}"
```

Comment: How does this associate the letter grade with the value?